# What's the most efficient way to store large Pandas Series with numpy arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, parquet

I have a `pandas` Series that contains `numpy` two-dimensional array in each row. It looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([np.random.rand(4, 3) for i in range(0, 4)])
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)], names = ['id1', 'id2'])

id1  id2
1    1      [[0.03782554831829077, 0.5265070448370034, 0.9...
     2      [[0.8542842542246349, 0.532639803094301, 0.390...
2    1      [[0.34916931374311333, 0.5820394142173778, 0.1...
     2      [[0.08834940949270964, 0.9464717661752107, 0.4...
dtype: object
```

However, the real data have over 50k of rows with 7140x3 array in each row. I need to store it on disk. I usually go for `.parquet` with large data files because of its efficient conversion, but I'm afraid it cannot handle `numpy` arrays as a column. `Pickle` seems to work fine, but it results in a file of 10GB size, so with many similar dataset I will easily run out of space. So I'd like to ask what's the most memory efficient way to store this sort of datasets?

Comment: 50000*7140*3*8  is 8.5G.  The pickle format for `ndarray` is the `npy` save, which is bascially a memory dump of the array's data buffer.  It's hard to be more 'memory efficient' than in-memory Series.

Comment: _I have a pandas Series that contains numpy two-dimensional array in each row._ Why? Can you provide some text for this?

Comment: Maybe float32 is also enough? This would result in 4.3GB filesize. If this isn't enough or maybe not acceptable you can also compress (lossless) the data. eg. using bloscpack https://github.com/Blosc/bloscpack#python-api

Comment: Did you try parquet?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the index with pickle and the values as a NumPy array:

```
np.stack(s.values).tofile(filepath) #saves as np.array of shape len(s)x7140x3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the file size stayed the same, so probably the data structure is not an issue here.

Comment: So I guess is not possible to be more efficient than this, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

For storing large datasets with numpy arrays efficiently, you can consider using **HDF5** (Hierarchical Data Format version 5).

```
pip install h5py
```

Find the quick start guide and documentation [here](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html).

Comment: `h5py` stores numpy arrays.  `pandas` uses a `pytables`/hdfstore layer on top of that..  I don't expect it to save space unless you can get compression to work effectively.